# HTML Variables into PHP Tag

Tags: php, web

I am just starting out in PHP/Html web development.
I have a basic page with a username and password field and a submit button.
I want to get the data from the username and password boxes into the php.

Here is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align = "center">Harro</h2>
    <form align = "center">
        Username: <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter"> 
        <?php

            ???

        ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to start by learning the basics. Read some tutorials and books. Although not complicated, what you're asking is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Read some tutorials on jQuery, Ajax and POST requests.

Comment: jQuery and Ajax are not the places to start. Start with basic PHP

Comment: First, read this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596157142.do Then try to solve your problem on your own. Then, and only then, come back here and ask a question if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the URI of the PHP program the form should be submitted to using the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="foo.php">
```

Then, *when the form is submitted*, PHP will populate the `$_GET` or `$_POST` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) with the data.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is learning to code PHP web-apps from ground-up.

Currently what you will get from answers is just the code to get the `Username` and `Password` from the user. But the main thing comes after that. Like validation, and checking the login information from the database and then retrieving it.

Personally, I would recommend you to read O'Reilly Media's [Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, and CSS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023487.do).

Answer (score 0):

add name attribute in submit button
eg: name="submit"

And

add attribute in form tag method="post"

and write php code at top

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     echo "USERNAME ".$_POST['firstname'];
     echo "PASSWORD ". $_POST['pwd'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: can you please help me in this to formatting actually i am new in this

Comment: @softsdev: That information is very, very easy to find. If you are a programmer worthy of the name you can find it yourself.

Comment: @softsdev Click edit. You'll see a toolbar. The `{}` button will format all selected text. Or, you can add 4 spaces in from of a line to format it.